# Does address-of operator return address of an object referenced by the variable

Tags: c++, addressof

This is different question from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247026/does-address-of-operator-return-address-of-an-object-referenced-by-the-variable), as here I'm using object type `struct`, instead of a value `23...`.

I'm reading [this chapter](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) on pointers and it states the following:

> The address of a variable can be obtained by preceding the name of a
>   variable with an ampersand sign (&), known as address-of operator. For
>   example:

```
MyStruct* myvar = new MyStruct();
&myvar; // what is this address?
```

Is my understanding correct that it's the address of an object `new MyStruct()`, not the variable itself? I don't yet have good understanding of how variables (not objects they reference) are stored, and it's very likely that they are not used at all when program is compiled.

Comment: Did you try and compile this?

Comment: `MyStruct myvar = new Struct();` isn't valid C++. You probably meant to write `MyStruct* myvar = new MyStruct();` in which case `foo = &myvar;` doesn't make any sense. Please fix your question, it can't be answered.

Comment: Replace cplusplus.com with one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @Lundin, thanks, updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247026/does-address-of-operator-return-address-of-value-referenced-by-the-variable): **No**, it isn't... It is the address of variable `myvar`...

**EDIT**

> so the actual bytes of new Struct() are stored under different address than a variable?

`new` return address of memory where "bytes" of `struct` are allocated. 
Value of `myvar` will be the address where "bytes" are placed in memory, and `&myvar` is the address where variable `myvar` is placed in memory.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|                     M E M O R Y                     |
-------------------------------------------------------
|   --------------                   ---------------  |
|   | myvar = 234| ----points to---> | new MyStruct|  |
|   --------------                   ---------------  |
|   ^                                ^                |
|   |                                |                |
|   address 1 (&myvar)               address 234      |
|                                                     |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks, so the actual bytes of `new Struct()` are stored under different address than a variable?

Comment: `new` return address of memory where "mytes" of struct are allocated. So value of myvar will be the address where "bytes" are placed in memory, and &myvar is the address vere variable myvar is placed in memory.

Comment: yes, I know that, so suppose it returned `234`, and that is the address of the first byte of an object created by `new Struct()`, my question is essentially `&myvar` returns `234` or some other address?

Comment: See my edit, I hope its clear enough. `234` is the value of `myvar`, the address will be different

Comment: thanks, it's clear now, so if `myvar` holds `address 2 `, how can I output it?

Comment: I've edited my question details, so you can remove this `BTW your code is plain wrong: you mus...`

Comment: Simply doing `cout << myvar << endl;`

Comment: just one more clarification, if I had `int myvar = 1232`, would I still get two addresses? Or would the address of the variable be actually the address of the first byte of the number `1232`?  Can you please draw a picture like you did for `new MyStruct`?

Comment: No It isn't. Address of `myvar` (i.e. `&myvar`) is the only address you can have. Value `1234` is placed in memory at address `&myvar`

Comment: thank you, so this assumption `Or would the address of the variable be actually the address of the first byte of the number 1232?` is correct?

Comment: got it, thanks, that where my original confusion comes from. I'm wondering why it is different from the original case with `new`, any comments to read about?

Comment: It is different because in that case at `myvar` address is stored the value of the address where the struct was allocated with new. So `myvar` always store a value, but the value has different "meanings"

Answer (score 2):

> *Is my understanding correct that it's the address of an object `new MyStruct()`, not the variable itself?*

No, it **is** the address of the variable `myvar` which was *initialized* with the object returned by `new Struct();`.

Comment: thanks, so the actual bytes of `new Struct()` are stored under different address than a variable?

Comment: For this code to compile, `myvar` has to be a pointer. So the question can't be answered, because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Maximus no, myvar point to the start of the address location, that's all. `&myvar` is where the `myvar` itself is located.

Answer (score 1):

What you get is basically *a copy of the pointer*. Here's how [you can prove it](http://ideone.com/9lgmLl):

```
int* ptr = new int(2);
int& i = *ptr;
std::cout<<i<<std::endl; //prints 2
ptr = new int(3); //now ptr points to another address
std::cout<<*ptr<<std::endl; //prints 3
std::cout<<i<<std::endl; //still prints 2!
```

Ignoring bad memory management here, you see that you just have a reference, which is a copy to a memory location. If you change the original pointer, it doesn't change. Does that answer your question?